Discord oAuth API - 400 error getting token from code
What I'm trying to do:
setup oauth discord logins on my website, I've setup the first part, identify email scope for getting the initial code, now that I've got the code, I'm unable to use the /oauth/token endpoint without getting a consistent 400 error.
I've attempted 1 thing so far, changing my Auth from Basic to inside of my post params, still didn't work:
final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://discord.com/api/v10/oauth2/token").openConnection();
try(AutoCloseable autoCloseable = () -> connection.disconnect()){
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    //connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((CLIENT_ID + ":" + CLIENT_SECRET).getBytes()));
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))){
        writer.write("grant_type=authorization_code&" +
                "code="+code+"&" +
                "redirect_uri=https://website/api/discord&" +
                "&client_secret=" + CLIENT_SECRET +
                "&client_id=" + CLIENT_ID);
        writer.flush();
        String s;
        while((s = reader.readLine()) != null){
            resp.getWriter().println(s);
        }
        resp.getWriter().flush();
    }
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

My error stacktrace:
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://discord.com/api/v10/oauth2/token
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1998)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1599)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:223)

